# C# CRUD with Access Database: Interactions cannot be executed (Not a valid file name)

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, oledb, oledbconnection

Im relatively new to c# and im working on a work at my university, which consist in verifying a switchboard, im working in a CRUD right now to edit, create and delete items for one column in a datagridview, so here is my problem.

To connect my project to the database im using try and catch, but it seems like im having trouble in the connection, everytime i try to edit, delete or create, i get an error from the catch saying "Not a valid file name".

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + Application.StartupPath + @"C:\\Verificação de Quadros Elétricos\\Verificação de Quadros Elétricos\\Databaseteste.accdb";
        string comando = "INSERT INTO Tabela Normas (Drills(according tto the norm EN 61439)values(@Drills(according tto the norm EN 61439))";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strcon);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(comando, con);

        com.Parameters.Add("@Drills(according tto the norm EN 61439)", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Save Well Succeded !");

        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }



    }
```

so heres the code to create a new item in the column, thanks for your time.

One thing out of the code that caught my attention and maybe means something is wrong with the database.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2hfm.jpg)

does this x on the database means it isnt connected?

Comment: Your path string is wrong. You are using verbatim string (@ prefix), still trying to escape the path separator. @"c:\\Veri...." should be @"c:\Veri...." and also other separators as well.

Also your insert command looks incorrect, if you have such a fieldName then enclose it with [ ]. For the parameter use a shorter valid identifier (ie: @drills).

Comment: what do you mean by field name?, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry it looks like it was not understood as a comment)

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
               @"C:\Data\Databaseteste.accdb";
        string comando = @"INSERT INTO [Tabela Normas] 
           ([Drills(according to the norm EN 61439)])
           values
           (@Drills)";

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strcon))
        using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(comando, con))
        {

        com.Parameters.Add("@Drills", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Save Well Succeded !");

        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If Application.StartupPath is under Program Files, then the location is read only. Keep that in mind.

Comment: I was careless sorry, you are saying Application.StartupPath and still using @"c:\...'. Application.StartupPath is a full path itself (but C:\ is one of the worst places you can choose for a database, I don't think your database is there and I assume it was a typo.). Use fullpath whereever your database is. Editing.

Comment: so where you´d recommend me to put my database?

Comment: In appdata. It is a special folder that its location might change. For a simpler start, you may put it into a read write folder that you create. ie: c:\Data

Comment: i think the error im getting constantly is because my database isnt connected to my code somehow, in the question, i edited and added a screenshot of my database in the code, maybe that can be useful.

Comment: so far, thank you for your time and for your comprehension.

Comment: That picture doesn't tell me anything (maybe because I am not a fan of access and wouldn't suggest it to anybody). Let's do this: Create a folder c:\Data, put your database there. I am going to edit the code using c:\Data as where the database file is (I also noticed your table name was "Tabela Normas" - that too needs to be enclosed in [ ].

Comment: i created a file there and moved my database to there, also enclosed "tabela normas", now what can i do?

Comment: I don't know if this is against SO rules really, hope not. Give me your email and if we can arrange an online meeting I can show in minutes.

Comment: i dont know either, but you can contact me through:cruddoubt@gmail.com, if we can arrange a online meeting it would be really helpfull, thanks in advance.